# Access the partition where I installed Wubi in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, partitioning, wubi

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS through Wubi on Windows XP.

I installed it in a partition (say J:) and the installation went fine.

I can access my other NTFS partitions normally in Ubuntu without any problem.

But lately I just figured that I could not see my J: partition (where I installed Wubi) in my Ubuntu. I need to access it badly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available under `/host` directory. Got me at first too, figured it out be checking `/etc/fstab`

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @PetrMarek :) glad to help